# Infragistics xamDataGrid child band visibility

Tags: xamdatagrid

I have a xamDataGrid. There are three child bands in the grid. I want to hide the 2nd band of this grid.
Any leads acceptable.

Comment: Hide band means hide labels or you don'e want that level to exist in grid?

Comment: Yes...I only want to hide band[2] from xamDatagrid...

Comment: add XamDataGrid code in the question

Comment: The item source of the grid is a class. That contains 3 groups. I want all the groups. But don't want to display all the groups in the grid.

Comment: give XAMl of XamDatagrid and class code also